# Adding XML Documentation to a Function

Tags: c#, .net

I got a Function that is basically this Method:

```
/// <summary>Extracts the parent id.</summary>
/// <param name="nameEntities">The name entities.</param>
/// <param name="tcdMakeId">The TCD make id.</param>
/// <returns>Parent Id.</returns>
public Nullable<int> ExtractParentId( IEnumerable<NameEntity> nameEntities, int childId )
{
    /* Do some Extraction here */
}
```

In the Method it is no problem at all to add nice XML documentation for parameter and so forth. But is there a Way to do this with a Function? The Intellisense of my colleague gives him nothing but Arg1, Arg2.

The Function would be:

```
private Func<IEnumerable<NameEntity>, int, Nullable<int>> ExtractParentId
{
    get
    {
        return this._extractParentId = this._extractParentId ??
            new Func<IEnumerable<NameEntity>, int, Nullable<int>>( ( nameEntities, childId ) =>
            {
                /* Do some Extraction here */
            } );
    }
}
```

Well I know this is not a perfect example, but I can't post the real code here ( corporate :/ and way to long ) but this is basicly a striped down version.

Thanks quite a lot,
Marc

Comment: that's not a function.  that's a read-only property

Comment: Are you asking "I have a property of type `Func<R,S,T>`, can I give it XML documentation so intellisense shows the same details for the property as it would a regular method?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me a lot like you're trying to reinvent the Delegate wheel:

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="nameEntities"></param>
/// <param name="childID"></param>
/// <returns></returns> <!--etc-->
private delegate Nullable<int> ExtractParentIdDelegate(IEnumerable<int> nameEntities, int childID);

/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
private ExtractParentIdDelegate FuncExtractParentId
{
    get
    {
        return this._extractParentId = this._extractParentId ?? new ExtractParentIdDelegate(delegate(IEnumerable<int> nameEntites, int childID)
                                                                    {
                                                                            //
                                                                    });
    }
}
```

Comment: You know, in Germany we have a saing "to miss the forest for the trees". Shurly simply making it a delegate solves the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the generic delegate `Func<...>`, declare a specific delegate type for this property and put the documentation as part of the delegate definition.  Then the property will show the documentation for the delegate.  That's where the *Arg1*, *Arg2* that you saw are coming from - the documentation for the `Func<R,S,T>`.

For example, try this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Using Func<int,int,int>, we get generic documentation
    /// </summary>
    public Func<int,int,int> UsingFunc{ get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Example of a delegate with XML documentation as if it was a method.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="left">Left operand</param>
    /// <param name="right">Right operand</param>
    /// <returns>Whatever it returns</returns>
    public delegate int CustomDelegate(int left, int right);

    /// <summary>
    /// Using a custom delegate to get full documentation.
    /// </summary>
    public CustomDelegate UsingCustomDelegate{ get; }
```

Comment: As I said obove... I must have had way to less sleep. Delegate is what I was looking for!